# How can validate ck editor using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, ckeditor

I'm trying to validate ck editor (`textarea`) but failed, can anyone let me know where the problem in following code, is this possible that ck editor validate by following code?

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#manageForm").validate(
        {
          debug: false,
            rules: { 
                description:{

                 required:true,
                 minlenght:10
                }
             }
        });
    });
```

### HTML

```
<form name="manageForm" id="manageForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="span6 autogrow"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to validate ck editor: my solution is using below code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#manageForm").validate(
            {
              debug: false,
                rules: { 

                    description:{
                         required: function() 
                        {
                         CKEDITOR.instances.description.updateElement();
                        },

                         minlength:10
                    }
                },
                messages:
                    {

                    description:{
                        required:"Please enter Text",
                        minlength:"Please enter 10 characters"


                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I have edited your code :
please look at this jsfiddle demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/81/)

Comment: can you tell me which js file need to use?

Comment: its not working should i need to use any js file...?

Comment: you need to import ckeditor.js  , jquery.validate.min.js , lcoastyles.css  . please look at this demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/82/)

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo: `minlenght:10` should be `minlength:10`